# Background location draining too much battery since iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, gps, ios9

I have an app that runs in background collecting GPS location and sending it to a server.
The app exists since iOS 7 or before.

When M7 came out, I managed to stop/start background location when the device is stopped or moving. This way, the app was consuming only 2-6% battery and the location monitoring was 100% effective. So I had a background GPS location monitoring app that was really battery friendly.

This was true until iOS 9.

The same app, which was consuming around 5%, is now consuming 30-60% in iOS 9/9.1.
I have tried so many things, but I don't see any reason for that battery usage difference.
I do realize that the battery percentage is a relative information, but I'm testing since iOS 9 came out and it is really draining more battery.

I run the app on iOS 8.2/8.4 and it consumes only 2-6%. The same version of app running on iOS 9/9.1 consumes around 40%!
M7 is working fine, GPS listener is stopped/started as intended. But the battery usage goes crazy on iOS 9.

If I don't enable GPS location at all, the app running in background consumes around 3% on iOS 9. But if I enable GPS location for a while and then stops it according to M7, the battery usage goes super high. So the problem is really GPS location.

It looks like that iOS is not turning off GPS hardware when I call [MyLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation].

This is how I initialize my location manager:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];  
locationManager.delegate = self;  
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;  
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates)]) {  
    [locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];  
}  
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)]) {  
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;  
    locationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOther;  
}
```

When I want to start it, I call:

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And to stop it, I call:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

I do repeat:

1. My location manager is not running all the time! I start and stop it according to M7 reports!
2. The same version of the app consumes much less battery on earlier iOS versions.

Anyone else noticed that?
Is there a bug or something with CLLocationManager since iOS 9?
Should I just accept that the same app consumes more battery now?
Is apple condemning apps that use background GPS location by showing more battery usage?

What can I do?

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome!

PS: I'm not questioning whether background location it is a nice thing to do. We have a legal usage.

Comment: did you find any solutions? we have seen the same problem since iOS 9

Comment: @memical unfortunately not. If you find any solution or any explanation, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: upgrading to 9.2.1 fixed it for me, the battery usage is back to 5-6% down from 40-60%.

Comment: @memical weird... I tested with iOS 9.2.1 and 9.3 beta. In both cases the battery usage went down to 20-25% for me. But it is still high compared to 2-6% that my app used to consume before iOS 9.

Comment: yes, for us too, in the first few days it stayed low, but now we see again high usage - even 80%. the difference was that i tested it on the highway. it seems while stationary the usage got to normal values, but when moving we still have it too high.

Comment: i asked support. they said that accessing (!!) and changing any location manager properties (filter, accuracy, ...) is an expensive operation. i am trying now to avoid this.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer did you find the solutions ?

Comment: @BisonCode unfortunately, no. I couldn't find anything on this, so I just accepted that it was draining more battery and I dropped that project.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Thanks for your comment, we have optimised this with the help of our senior iOS developer at http://BisonCode.com.

Comment: @EduardoHerzer is this now fixed with iOS 10 x....? did you find any update regarding this...?

Comment: @AbiramiBala Sorry, I can't say how it is in iOS 10.x. I'm not working with background location anymore, I dropped that project. Are you still facing this battery drain problem?

Comment: @EduardoHerzer Im not facing any issue.. but our clients are asking that it might be happens in future. Thats why im confusing.